# Is it that constructor is called only in case an object of a class is made?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

What i know as of now that a constructor is called when an object is created. I also know that its not possible to create an object of an Abstract Class.

But when i run this piece of code i see the following :-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Pet {
public:
    Pet(){cout<<"in base constructor\n";}

    virtual ~Pet() = 0;  //making pet abstract by making drstructor pure virtual
};

Pet::~Pet() {
    cout << "~Pet()" << endl;
}

class Dog : public Pet {
    public:
    Dog(){cout<<"in drvd constructor\n";}

    ~Dog() {
        cout << "~Dog()" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Pet* p = new Dog; // Upcast
    delete p; // Virtual destructor call
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run its output is :-

```
in base constructor
in drvd constructor
~Dog()
~Pet()
```

why is constructor for Pet getting called even though its an abstract class and no object creation is allowed for it? So it boils down to finally is constructor called only in case of object creation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> its not possible to create an object of an Abstract Class

Don't take this ad-litteram. **You can't create an object whose actual type is abstract**.

But, if you implement that class (extend it and implement all pure virtual methods in it) and instantiate the new class, an object of the original abstract base class will be created as part of the new class.

Inheritance is a `is-a` relationship. `Dog` is a `Pet`. When you create a `Dog`, you create a `Pet`. But you can't create a `Pet` on its own.

Comment: *You can't create an object whose actual type is abstract, but if you inherit from it, it will be constructed.* The custom rule invented here is not appropriate.If the abstract class has an pure virtual and it is not a destructor, then derived class **MUST** define the pure virtual method, without which the derived class is an Abstract class too & no object construction whatsoever is possible.

Comment: @Als thought that was obvious.

Comment: It is definitely not obvious to someone who asks this Q. -1 Because the answer is even more misleading after the edit. *You can't create an object whose actual type is abstract, but if you inherit from it, the inheriting class is not abstract* , ***ONLY IF DERIVED CLASS DEFINES THE PURE VIRTUAL METHODS OF THE BASE CLASS***

Comment: @Als Yeah you are correct . But here Pet was made abstract class by making destructor as pure virtual in which case you dont necessary need derive class to define the pure virtual function

Comment: @Als agree, sorry bout that. I realized the mistake in formulation only after re-reading the edit. It was supposed to be an `and` there.

Comment: @Ritesh nope, he's right. I wanted to say something but wrote something else.

Comment: Removed the Downvote.All Good, Still you could actually make your rule more readable, its a little wordy, though its correct.I say this because in time people will lookup this answer as an rule and rules if you quote be clear and concise.

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is that "it is not possible to create a *most-derived* object of an abstract class". But objects can also be base-subobjects of more-derived objects, in which case they still need to be constructed.

(An object can be a subobject in three ways: A member subobject of a class-type object, a base subobject of a derived class-type object, or an element of an array.)

Comment: So these does that mean Pet object will be a subobject for an object of Dog ?

Comment: @Ritesh: A subobject, Yes. Every `Dog` *is-a* `Pet`, which means every `Dog` object has characteristics of an `Dog` + characteristics of a `Pet`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can create a instance of Dog, but not Pet. i.e

```
Pet p; //Not possible, as destructor is abstract.
Dog d; //Allowed, because you derived from pet and ~pet( ) is defined.
```

The general sequence is if you create an object of a target class, the constructors are invoked in the order of base class -> child level -> ... -> target class. The destructors follow the reverse order.

To visualize this,think of target class is a superset of all its parent class/es.
Here , Dog is a super set of Pet.

Comment: my question was not on order of constructor or sedtructor call but . Why in case of an abstract class am i getting my constructor called if an object is not created ?

Comment: Put in simple terms, When a class is defined abstract, it means that the class cannot be constructed standalone as some of the mandatory functionality of the class is not defined. The way to create an object of this is you derive from this class and ensure that all mandatory functionality is defined i.e all pure virtual functions and members. Now when you create an object of derived class, an object of your abstract class is created as a sub object of your derived class and constructor of abstract class is invoked to initialize the contents of the subobject.